# How to judge the complexity of SQL queries

Tags: mysql, time-complexity, query-optimization, complexity-theory, space-complexity

Any resource where it is explained how to judge the complexity of SQL queries would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most, if not all DBMS's allow you to get plan information about a query. While a simple looking sql *might* result in a complex plan and vice-versa, it might be a good starting point nonetheless.

Comment: If you mean how can I assess how complex a query will need to be to complete as task I think the question is off topic for this site please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what you can ask and read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#:~:text=Computational%20complexity%20theory%20focuses%20on,steps%2C%20such%20as%20an%20algorithm. as a starter for computational complexity theory

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question appears to be about computational complexity theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(By "complexity", I assume you mean "slowness"?)  Some tips:

- Subqueries may or may not slow down a query a lot.
- `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` -- when both are present but different:  Usually requires two sorts.
- Usually only a single index is used per `SELECT`.
- `OR` is almost always inefficient.  Switching to `UNION` allows multiple indexes to be efficiently used.
- `UNION ALL`, with a few restrictions, is more efficient than `UNION DISTINCT` (because of the dedupping pass)
- Non-sargeable expressions cannot use an index, hence severely inefficient.
- If the entire `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are handled by a single index can `LIMIT` be efficiently handled.  (Else it must collect all the stuff, sort it, only then can it peel off a few rows.)
- Entity-Attribute-Value schema is inefficient.
- UUIDs and GUIDs are inefficient on very large tables.
- A composite index is often better than a single-column index.
- A "covering" index is somewhat better.
- Sometimes, especially when a `LIMIT` is involved, it is better to turn the query inside-out.  That is start with a subquery that finds the few `ids` that you need, *then* reaches back into the same table and into other tables to get the rest of the desired columns.
- "Windowing functions" are poorly implemented in MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10.2.  They are useful for "groupwise-max" and "hierarchical schemas".  Until the Optimizer improves, I declare them to be "complex".
- Recent versions have recognized "row constructors"; previously they were a performance hit.
- Having an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id hurts performance in certain cases; helps in others.

`EXPLAIN` (or `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`) tells you what is going on *now*; it fails to tell you how to rewrite the query or what better index to add.

More indexing tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql  In that link, see "Handler counts" for a good way to measure complexity for specific queries.  I use it for comparing query formulations, etc, even without populating a large table to get usable timings.

Give me a bunch of Queries; I'll point out the complexities, if any, in each.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the official MySQL documentation on Query Execution Plan:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html

You could use the EXPLAIN command to get more information about your query.